# Tensorflow multiplication 3D tensor by 2D matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying multiply 3D tensor by 2D matrix, but with one unknown dimension.
I checked all posts about that here, but without I don't found what I want.

I have these parameters:

T - shape (M,N)

L - shape (?,M,M)

F - shape (?, N)

I want to do multiplication L * T * F with output shape (?,M).

I tried expand dimensions etc.

Unfortunately, I always lost ?-dimension.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that like this.

```
L --> [?, M, M]
T --> [M, N]
tensordot(L,T) axes [[2], [0]] --> [?,M, N]
F --> [?, N] --> expand axis --> [?, N, 1]
matmul [?, M, N], [?, N, 1] --> [?, M, 1] --> squeeze --> [?, M]
```

putting together:

```
tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf.tensordot(L,T, axes=[[2],[0]]),F[...,None]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a learner I found the question and answer quite cryptic. So I simplified it for myself.

```
import tensorflow as tf

L = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 5, 5])

T = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[ 5, 10])

F = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[ None, 10])

print ((tf.tensordot(L,T, axes=[[2],[0]])).get_shape)

# This is more cryptic. Not really sure.
#print(F[...,None].get_shape) 
print( tf.expand_dims(F,2).get_shape)

finaltensor = tf.matmul(tf.tensordot(L,T, axes=[[2],[0]]),F[...,None])

print (finaltensor.get_shape)

squeezedtensor = tf.squeeze(finaltensor)

print (tf.shape(squeezedtensor))
```

Everything printed except the last line is clear.

```
<bound method Tensor.get_shape of <tf.Tensor 'Tensordot:0' shape=(?, 5, 10) dtype=float32>>

<bound method Tensor.get_shape of <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(?, 10, 1) dtype=float32>>

<bound method Tensor.get_shape of <tf.Tensor 'MatMul:0' shape=(?, 5, 1) dtype=float32>>

Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)
```